# Limit for number of questions where tag can be added by tag-creator soon after the creation of tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging, rate-limiting

Occasionally we have seen a situation like this: A user creates a new tag. The tag is then discussed on meta and the consensus is that the tag is not suitable and should be completely removed. However, it takes some time until somebody notices the tag and brings up the issue on meta. And then the discussion on meta might go on for some time. So it might happen that until the whole things is decided, the tag might grow to about 100 questions. (Especially if the tag-creator was very active in adding tag to new questions. This might happen especially if the user's motivation was mainly to get [taxonomist badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) and not whether the new tag is actually useful.)

This would mean that such large number of questions is [bumped](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bumping/info) twice. First when the tag is added. And later, if the outcome of the discussion is that the tag should be removed, they are bumped again during the clean-up.<sup>1</sup>

**Suggestion:** Maybe it would be reasonable to limit number of questions where the tag can be added by *the user who created the tag* for some *limited period of time after* the creation of the tag. (For example, numbers like 5 questions per day for one month do not seem too restrictive.)<sup>2</sup>

I think the tags which are actually going to be useful will probably be added organically by other users anyway. Implementing this suggestion would prevent users who are mainly badge-hunting from adding many questions to the new tag immediately after the creation of the tag.

It is also possible that somebody creates a new tag with good intentions, but is unaware of some reasons why the tag is not suitable. (The tag-creator might be unaware of previous discussion on meta related to this specific tag or related to criteria when creation of new tags is useful.) In such situation this gives a bit more time for others to notice a problematic tag before it grows too much.

Of course, I am aware that there can be legitimate cases where limit like this does not make sense. For example, if a new tag has already been discussed on meta and it is generally agreed that it is a good tag, the limit suggested here might be a bit contra-productive. (I can quote the ongoing retagging [of the (partition) tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27172/revisiting-the-partitions-tag) as an example.) So this proposal might prevent some problems, but also cause some problems.

**Additional question:** I'd be grateful also for other suggestions which might help mitigate the problems described above (i.e., problems with over-eager tag-creators). Especially if you find this specific feature request not suitable, it would be nice to consider some alternatives.

---

<sup>1</sup>Moderators have some limited tools by which they can remove a tag without actually bumping the questions. This can be done by merging it into another tag. (More details can be found here: [Can you change the name of a tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25699#25701)) However, this can be used only if *all remaining questions* in the newly created tag also fit some other existing tag. So typically at least part of the questions with the new tag has to be retagged manually. (Here is [one specific example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34614415#34614415) where this was used.)

<sup>2</sup>I am aware that this would probably be *more suitable for [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com)* since it would be a change influencing all sites in the network. But still, I wanted to ask here first. (And then possibly move this feature request to the main meta - but only in case that the feedback here is positive. Alternatively, if there is some better suggestion how to deal with the problem, it can be posted as a feature request on the main meta instead.) Another reason is that I am mainly familiar with this one site. I hope that some users who are active here and also on other sites might be able to tell me whether something like this was discussed elsewhere and whether other sites have similar problems. And I am hoping that even if this feature request is not approved, posting it here on meta still might raise an awareness of this problem among users of this site and perhaps users creating new tags will not add too many questions at the same time to a new tag. (In the light of some tag-related discussions we had during this year, achieving at least this would be probably good.)

Comment: This was posted partly as a reaction to the situation I have seen quite recently - a tag which was ony a few hours old and it already had over 50 questions. (Even if the tag turns out to be useful and remains on the site, this seems to me a bit excessive.)

Comment: And I will add that not too long ago there was a discussion involving a tag that had over 100 questions after a few days. (But at least this is a bit less extreme than the example mentioned in the previous comment.) Since I want to keep this discussion general, I have not linked to these specific instances. (However, the users who follow situations with new tags can probably easily guess which tags I am talking about.)

Comment: Yes. Can we please? I'd say that a reasonable limitation is that new tags get a "beta status" which needs to be cleared by the moderators, or if more than six people participate in "positive tagging efforts" which are not canceled out over a week. Or something like that. That sounds complicated, tedious, but all in all, I don't see any other way to prevent someone from creating a new tag, instantly trashing 50 more questions, and then retiring quietly to their summer home in the Hamptons.

Comment: I have posted now the corresponding feature request on meta.SE: [Do not allow massive retagging by the tag-creator shortly after creation of a new tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306062). We will see how it will be received there.

Comment: And this happened again, this time with [tag:logical-translation] which was created and after five days the creator decided that it's probably fine and went on to tag 70+ questions. Can we please try and push this stronger?

Comment: @AsafKaragila As you can see, I have [posted a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/306062/revisions) on the Meta Stack Exchange question to attract more attention. I am not sure whether I can do much beyond that. If you have some suggestions on the linked question and suggestions about specifics of the implementation of this feature, maybe you could post answer there - this could encourage other users to comment or your suggestion or add some more feedback in their own answers.

Comment: Ugh. I don't like the idea of starting to participate on more SE websites.

Comment: What about an option (Checkbox) "Don't Bump Question" for Tag changes only?

Comment: @Royi You can find some older related discussions. Mainly this discussion on [meta.se]: [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567) and other [posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/122567). And also a few posts on this site: [“Minor edit” feature for trusted users](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23159), [Would you like to have the option to edit a question without it being bumped to the main page?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22171) or ...

Comment: ...[About making small edits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3820). However, this seems only tangential to the issue raised in this question, which are potential problems caused by the users who create new tags. (And if it is done without bumping, it just makes the situation worse - since it might take longer to notice new problematic tags.)

Comment: Those issues could be solved by many other ways. Like a report of daily new tags, etc... Not every issue should be seen only by what happens on first page :-). Anyhow, there are others to figure this out. It seems the policy is strict even for users with enough credit.