# Which tag should be used for (elementary-logic)?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922578/math%c3%a9matical-logic-find-the-treasure) question, which was tagged "linear algebra". I wasn't sure what to retag it as. I thought about (logic), but that's for advanced mathematical logic, model theory and whatnot. We need a tag which is to (logic) what (elementary-set-theory) is to (set-theory), or what (probability) is to (probability-theory). The tag description for (logic) suggests (puzzles), which is not a good fit here.

1. What tag should be used for questions like this?
2. Can we mention that tag in the tag description for (logic)?

Comment: I will point out that there was a [suggestion to create (elementary-logic) tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28150/can-the-tag-logic-translation-be-useful/28236#28236). (But the discussion there was only very short and it would probably have been more suitable as a separate question.) Personally, I'd consider ([tag:logic]) a suitable tag for the linked question. The tags ([tag:puzzle]) and ([tag:propositional-calculus]) could perhaps be added too. But it's better to wait and see what user that are more active in the (logic) tag have to say about this.