# Relating to create a new tag named "wronskian"

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

I have created a new tag named "[wronskian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wronskian)" and given the full details about it and also I fit  some questions relating this new tag.

I just want to know **is it acceptable for this site?**

If all goes well, I shall attach the rest of the questions.

I want a suitable opinion about that. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'll just add that the suggested edits for the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1239577) and [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1239578) are (at the moment) still pending.

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Comment: In the future, ask first and do later.

Comment: Certainly, I will do so.

Comment: tag-wiki and tag-excerpt are approved now. Shall I continue tagging questions on it? @Martin Sleziak , Asaf Karagila

Comment: @nmasanta I think it's better to wait a bit to see what kind of feedback you get from this question. After all, several past discussions here on meta suggest that it's not ideal to retag many questions *immediately* after the tag creation. For example: [Limit for number of questions where tag can be added by tag-creator soon after the creation of tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27492) and some [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/27492).

Comment: Okay. By the way, thanks for your time. @Martin Sleziak , Asaf Karagila

Comment: Can any one please explain, why this downvote  ? It may help me in future.

Comment: The tag seems reasonable to me. Since no one said anything against the tag specifically, I'd assume the votes are more for failure to ask first, and maybe for not using the dedicated thread. But, all things considered, you proceeded pretty well for somebody creating a tag. Thanks for trying to contribute to the tagging system.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: For future reference, the best place to discuss new tags is in [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29718/12952) meta thread. That said, this seems like a good tag suggestion to me.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for this @AlexanderGruber