# What is the etiquette of tag creation and editing?

Tags: discussion, tagging, editing, etiquette, retagging

In this years [Tag management](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32974/tag-management-2021) thread, I've suggested the creation of the tags [hochschild-cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hochschild-cohomology) and [a-infinity-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-infinity-algebras). Let's say for the sake of argument that this suggestion is well received and not contested and that I go ahead and create them.

I will be editing my own relevant questions to include these tags (which is part of the reason why I suggested them in the first place, because I spend a lot of time learning about them and will likely have more questions about them in the future), but what is the etiquette for editing other peoples old questions just to include them?

The reason I ask is that I seem to remember a while ago there being complaints on the meta about the active questions tab being spammed by edits of old questions to include a newly created tag. But on the other hand, it seems important to update old questions so they can be searched effectively.

Is there a rule of thumb for what's considered an acceptable amount of editing? Or is it best to just leave old questions alone and let a new tag succeed or fail based on future questions?

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-much-bumping-is-too-much for a suggestion of maximum 5 on the main page at a time.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for that, I'll take a look. I'd not seen that question when I was searching for duplicates!

Comment: A related conversation in chat: [Retagging with newly created tag (how fast and other advice)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/retagging-with-newly-created-tag-how-fast-and-other-advice). Related issues were discussed a bit also here: [Limit for number of questions where tag can be added by tag-creator soon after the creation of tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27492).